# Setting Cookies for A/B Testing

Tags: javascript, cookies, ab-testing

I am trying to set up an A/B test where the cookie will appear to 50% of the users. I have the option to place the cookie JavaScript in a field called "Head Include" of the targeted page's HTML's head, but the cookie is not appearing. The following is my script:

```
document.cookie = 'cname=true; Secure';
```

The cookie works when I place the script code in the HTML's head on the domain's site level. I have place a setting for the cookies to appear at a specific path. See following

```
document.cookie = 'cname=true; Secure; path=/test';
```

But I don't want to use the above script because I want to apply the cookie to a targeted page that will only show for 50% of targeted users and not to the site with a designated path assigned because then the cookie will show 100% of the time for that page, thus defeating the purpose of a A/B test.

My question is can a cookie be set on a specific page's HTML head and not the domain's HTML head? (Please note that names have be generalized in the code for privacy reasons)

Comment: I dont really understand the question... You want to include a javascript snippet in all of your pages but it should only place a cookie if the page is on a specific path?

Comment: No. I do not want to apply to all pages within a domain but to only one specific targeted page.

Answer (score 0):

*I am still not sure if I got the problem.*

You are using some kind of CMS and this CMS has the option to include scripts on a specific page ("Head include" on the target page) or an all pages ("HTML head" on domain site level). The first does not work, the latter does, but you dont want your cookie script executed on all pages.

Without seeing the generated HTML code of the (not working) target page we can't find out why its not working. If you can post a link to a prepared page (a page where the script is included and the cookie is not created) that could help to solve the problem.

Another option, without knowing the acutal problem would be shipping the script to all pages **but** filter the actual execution to a specific file path or url parameter. Example:

```
// let current = new URL(location.href); // use this to get the current url of the browser
let current = new URL('https://www.someurl.net/some_directory/some_file.ext?a=yes&b=12345'); // just an example url
if (current.searchParams.has('a') && current.searchParams.get('a') === 'yes') {
    // put your cookie script here, it will be executed only if the url has an a parameter and if that parameter has the value 'yes'
}
```

Have a look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) for an overview of the properties provided by the URL class